# Removal of clearcase views involves any housekeeping?

Tags: clearcase

Removing views which outlived its purpose, simple removal(Removing a view and its related records from a VOB) or should we perform any sort of housekeeping on the branches, elements etc. the views have been used to amend?

Comment: Question Is not clear.You mean UIViews of your app?

Answer (score 1):

No: the versions/branches can exist independently from the views.

You can simply do a `cleatool rmview` (in order to remove the tag and unregister the view).

The only cleanup you can do is to remove the checked out versions which are still recorded by a vob (even when a view has been removed):

```
cleartool descr -l vob:\avob | grep uuid
```

Then:

```
cleartool rmview --force -vob \avob -uuid an_uuid
```