# in multisite environment, how to find out which site has clearcase view uuid?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

```
$  cleartool rmstream stream:tiger@/vobs/forest
Remove stream
"stream:tiger@/vobs/forest"?  [no] yes
cleartool: Error: No tag in region for view "d6ca911d.229a41bb.942b.fd:ed:f2:bb:5c:f8".
cleartool: Error: Unable to remove stream "stream:tiger@/vobs/forest".
```

how to find out which site has clearcase view uuid d6ca911d.229a41bb.942b.fd:ed:f2:bb:5c:f8?

Answer (score 0):

The [IBM technote swg21127922](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21127922) does list a MultiSite environment and the view existing at a different replica site as a possible cause for this error message.

It might not be mandatory to switch to the site referencing that view to move forward though.

The steps described to resolve the issue involve removing the view by its uuid in the pvob of the stream.
I used that technique (`rmview --uuid`) before in "[Removal of clearcase views involves any housekeeping?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21608697/6309)".

For instance:

```
cleartool lsstream -l stream_name@\pvob.
```

The output will include:

```
views:
98573bec.d7e34570.a71c.e8:ab:7c:50:d4:02
```

Then:

```
ct desc -l vob:\ford_pvob
```

The output include:

```
VOB holds objects from the following views:
f15eagle:d:\ClearCase_Storage\views\RATIONAL\evchan\evchan_proj1_2.vws  [uuid 98573bec.d7e34570.a71c.e8:ab:7c:50:d4:02]
```

> You will need change directory (cd) into the PVOB
>
> Example:

```
W:\>cd ford_pvob

W:\ford_pvob>
```

Remove the view reference from the PVOB using, cleartool rmview -uuid uuid_number

> Note: By adding the `-all` switch, you will ensure to remove the view reference from the PVOB and any UCM Component VOBs that may also have a reference from this view; `cleartool rmview -all -uuid uuid_number`.
>   In this particular example, the `-all` was not required since we are only removing the view reference from the PVOB.
>
> Example:

```
W:\ford_pvob>ct rmview -uuid 98573bec.d7e34570.a71c.e8:ab:7c:50:d4:02
Removed references to view "f15eagle:d:\ClearCase_Storage\views\RATIONAL\evchan\evchan_proj1_2.vws" from VOB "\ford_pvob".
```

> Now the stream can be removed, using `cleartool rmstream stream_name@\pvob`
>
> Example:

```
W:\ford_pvob>ct rmstream evchan_proj1_2@\ford_pvob
Remove stream "evchan_proj1_2@\ford_pvob"?  [no] y
Removed stream "evchan_proj1_2@\ford_pvob" .
```