# ClearCase error, registry does not contain VOB with UUID

Tags: migration, uuid, clearcase

I am in the process of migrating a very large multisite installation to newer OS platforms. Running ClearCase 9. In one particular migration stage all the VOBs appear to have migrated correctly, ct lsvob -s -host xxxx shows no VOBs remaining on the old server, but now I am getting packets stuck in the incoming bin on that old server. I assume it has to do with devs who still had views open before the migration, but the problem is that mt lspacket is complaining that it cannot find a VOB with a single UUID in the registry. Packets are piling up, and they are all complaining about the same UUID, so I assume they are all related to one VOB. ct lsvob -uuid xxxx says it cannot find a VOB with that UUID.

How would I go about correcting this?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Unable to find replica in registry for vob “466198fa.195fllda.9971.00:01:83:23:e2:3b”

Comment: And this [support page](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/checkout-results-unable-find-replica-registry-vob-object-id-error) would not  help?

Comment: We are working on it. It's a complicated problem, made worse by Clearcase throwing errors out of the blue with migrated VOBs. I really, really wish our customer would quit making our life impossible by mandating the use of it. I'd rather be using Gitlab and Artifactory.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [`multitool lspacket`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearcase/9.0.2?topic=reference-lspacket#wp2473), check if a `multitool lspacket –long /usr/tmp/packet1` (one of the packet listed by `multitool lspacket`) helps (a bit like the old CC7.0 [`multitool lspacket -l -dump`](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/identifying-clearcase-multisite-packet-fragments-version-70))

If this is linked to dev views, check if you can get the a [`cleartool rmview --force -vob \avob -uuid an_uuid`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21608697/6309) is still possible, to make sure there is no view referencing the old Vob.

Answer (score 0):

The packets are getting routed to the old server by the other sites. It has nothing to do with developer views.

@VonC's lspacket -long answer will give you the name of the sending replica... Where you'll have to describe the target replica to see what it currently thinks the host is for the moved replica.

In the interim, you can copy/move the sync packets to the new server and the should import fine.

Assuming that you use the default jobs, and don't use -out to change the default packet names, running run multitool lspacket on the receiving host, you will show you names like "sh_o_sync_P50-rep_2022-11-14T160519-0500_17508." In this case, "P50-rep" is the name of the SENDING replica.

You will also see a line reading:

```
VOB family identifier is: 19fd6066.dbf111e1.9886.44:37:e6:60:fc:96
```

cleartool lsvob -family {above UUID} will identify the VOB whose sync packet this is.

```
* \bc-linuxtest        \\this-is-the-vob-server-host\vobstore\bc-linuxtest.vbs public (replicated)
```

You can then combine that information to locate the sending site since the describe would look something like this:

```
replica "P50-rep"
  created 2018-04-10T08:50:15-04:00 by CC VOB Admin (vobadm2.ccusers@Bullwinkle)
  "Test replica 3."
  replica type: unfiltered
  master replica: P50-rep@\bc-linuxtest
  request for mastership: enabled
  owner: PROD\vobadm
  group: PROD\ccusers
  host: "this-is-the-vob-server-host"
  identities: preserved
  permissions: preserved
```

Once you go there, you will be able to see what IT thinks the replica host is, and then we can make it know where the replica is now... By hook or by crook if need be. However, the "by crook" method would mean that you need to open a support case to get the tool and the steps to use it.

My guess is that the problem replica is:

1. The problem replica is self mastering, and
2. Does not send updates to at least one "upstream" replica.

Comment: Got it. That should help.

Comment: No it did not...

Comment: If you use default sync options, the packet name tells you the sending replica name.

Comment: @JuanJimenez Perhaps this helps? An actual support case would be a lot faster than the multi-day lag we're getting here.

Comment: We resolved the issue. A migration was done incorrectly and the vobs were "copied" to the wrong storage location. Once we figured that out we were able to reverse the process and restore the vobs.